# binary_crossentropy or categorical_crossentropy

Tags: python-3.x, keras

I am doing a multi-label image classification with 10 classes, I have 1981 Data and the labeled data are only 1000 from 1981.

I use this configuration

```
#begin model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(filters=16, kernel_size=(5, 5), activation="relu", input_shape=(400,400,1)))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=(5, 5), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=(5, 5), activation="relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=(5, 5), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(79, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(10, activation='sigmoid'))

model.summary()
```

with

```
sgd = optimizers.SGD(lr=0.001, momentum=0.9, decay=1e-6, nesterov=True)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=sgd, metrics=['accuracy'])
```

with that compile configuration, I got 65% of accuracy with nan loss, while if I'm using the binary_crossentropy I only got 10% of accuracy with nan loss too, I'm kinda confused with this compile configuration, which loss configuration should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must continue to use 'Categorical Crossentropy' for this problem as the target feature contains 10 classes.

The 'Binary Crossentropy' loss function must be used when only 2 classes are present in the target feature.

Comment: thanks for answering, I follow the tutorial for multi-label classification from this site, [https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2019/04/build-first-multi-label-image-classification-model-python/], It said that in order to perform multi-label classification u should use binary_crossentropy